# Swift 5 Custom Textfield Delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, textfield

Ever since I updated my Xcode and project to Swift 5,
I have this incredibly weird issue with specific textfields.
These text fields have a custom class to allow a response to a swipe action. They also have a special response to a standard touch. When the text field is touched, the textFieldShouldBeginEditing function suppresses the keyboard raise and instead launches a custom pull out value selection menu.
All was working perfectly until the update, where, whenever I start my Xcode up (after a day or two) and load my app, the textFieldShouldBeginEditing for these fields is never called!

What cures them (riduculously) is going to each View Controller that has one of these custom textfields - and making a single stroke edit to the page.
Then, when I reload, the textfields on that particular view are good again.

But the problem happens all over again, a few days later after I reload the app.
And I can't seem to replicate the problem by merely shutting down Xcode or even my computer. It seems it has to be shut down for some random amount of time or something.
...I don't know what causes this.

One other point - is that the IBOutlets for the custom selection pane is on a parent Class that is parent to all of these view controllers.
It would take a ton of writing to distribute all of the parent codes to all of the children view controllers.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var boolVal = true
    switch textField.tag {
    case 11: boolVal = false; launchSelection(textField)
    case 12: boolVal = false; launchSelection(textField)
    default: boolVal = true; shutThatStupidSideBar()
    }
    textFieldTag = textField.tag
    return boolVal
}
func launchSelection(_ tf:UITextField) {
    selectionPane.textfield = tf
    switch tf.tag {
    case 11: selectionPane.tableData = lm.retreiveList("provider")                                //11 = Owner
    case 12: selectionPane.tableData = lm.retreiveList("\(currentSettings.defUnitsStrand)GaugeStrand") //12 = Strand Gauge
    default: break
    }
    toggleSideBar()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Check `UITextField` delegate to `UIViewController` in storyboard
2. Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to viewController code like This:

   `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`
3. Use this sample code:

   ```swift
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       print("Test")
       return true
   }
   ```

Comment: All are covered. And I have done numerous tests - line by line checking when problem occurs. Nothing in 'textFieldShouldBeginEditing' runs. Its bypassed; as like many other text field functions I presume. But all the delegate code is in place. And remember. This only happens when I load my app for the first time after a few days. And when I edit the View Controller page in any way (just adding a space for example), the problem for that page goes away again!